# Why does embedding vector multiplied by a constant in Transformer model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, attention-model

I am learning to apply **Transform model** proposed by [Attention Is All You Need](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762) from tensorflow  official document [Transformer model for language understanding](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/text/transformer).

As section [Positional encoding](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/text/transformer#positional_encoding) says:

> Since this model doesn't contain any recurrence or convolution,
>   positional encoding is added to give the model some information about
>   the relative position of the words in the sentence.
>
> **The positional encoding vector is added to the embedding vector**.

My understanding is to add `positional encoding vector` directly to `embedding vector`. But I found `embedding vector` multiplied by a constant when I looked at the code.

The code in section [Encoder](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/text/transformer#encoder) as follows:

```
class Encoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff, input_vocab_size, 
               rate=0.1):
    super(Encoder, self).__init__()

    self.d_model = d_model
    self.num_layers = num_layers

    self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_vocab_size, d_model)
    self.pos_encoding = positional_encoding(input_vocab_size, self.d_model)


    self.enc_layers = [EncoderLayer(d_model, num_heads, dff, rate) 
                       for _ in range(num_layers)]

    self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate)

  def call(self, x, training, mask):

    seq_len = tf.shape(x)[1]

    # adding embedding and position encoding.
    x = self.embedding(x)  # (batch_size, input_seq_len, d_model)
    x *= tf.math.sqrt(tf.cast(self.d_model, tf.float32))
    x += self.pos_encoding[:, :seq_len, :]

    x = self.dropout(x, training=training)

    for i in range(self.num_layers):
      x = self.enc_layers[i](x, training, mask)

    return x  # (batch_size, input_seq_len, d_model)
```

We can see `x *= tf.math.sqrt(tf.cast(self.d_model, tf.float32))` before `x += self.pos_encoding[:, :seq_len, :]`.

So why does embedding vector multiplied by a constant before adding positional encoding in Transformer model?

Comment: Seems weird indeed, it would make since if it was `/=` referring to the normalizing factor in equation (1) in the paper

Comment: @bluesummers The normalizing factor has been implemented in the document but is not here. The normalizing factor is part of `self-attention` should be after the addition of `embedding vector` and `positional encoding`, so I can't understand `embedding vector` multiplying by a constant.

Comment: I get ya, revised it again and it indeed seems like a mistake

Comment: @bluesummers I found that tensorflow's official code also uses this method of calculation. The description of the [offical code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/9d53a5136f9997c82da089de6bab2d5ed7fce764/official/transformer/model/embedding_layer.py#L89) is `#Scale embedding by the sqrt of the hidden size`.

Comment: Did you find any rationale about why is it done?

Comment: @bluesummers No, I haven't found any theoretical explanation.

Comment: @giser_yugang I found a possible explanation here https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/88159/113304. Please refer

Answer (score 17):

Looking around it, I found this argument [1](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-code-the-transformer-in-pytorch-24db27c8f9ec):

> The reason we increase the embedding values before the addition is to
>   make the positional encoding relatively smaller. This means the
>   original meaning in the embedding vector won’t be lost when we add
>   them together.

Comment: Interesting... because I chanced upon this question while googling an answer for - how do I ensure that the positional embeddings (which are a relatively weak signal in my model) do not significantly mess up with the actual input data embeddings. Was thinking of reducing dimensions of positions etc. But a scalar multiplication to magnify the I/p data embeddings seems to be a better option. It seems logical. But is this the reason? cfb below seems to think otherwise

Answer (score 3):

I believe the reason for this scaling has nothing to do with the scale applied at the attention layers. It is likely because the transformer shares the weights of the embedding layer and the output softmax. The scales you would use for the embeddings is different than the scale you use for a fully connected layer.

Some implementations of the transformer use this scaling even though they don't actually share the embedding weights at the output layer, but that is probably kept there for consistency (or by mistake). Just make sure that the initialization of your embeddings is consistent.